# Yii use model in a command

Tags: php, yii, model, console

I've got a Yii application and I'm trying to add a command to it.

protected/commands/SendMessageCommand.php

```
class SendMessageCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
    public function run($args) {
        $messages = Message::model()->findAll(array('type' => 'S', 'sent' => null, 'scheduled_for' => array('$ne' => null)));
        [....]
```

/protected/config/console.php

```
[....]
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'Phrizz Console',

'preload'=>array('log'),

    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.forms.*',
        [....]
```

When I'm trying to run

```
$ yiic sendmessage
```

I'm getting

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Message' not found in /protected/commands/SendMessageCommand.php on line 7
```

How do I access model in command line script?

Yii 1.1.4

Comment: Just to clarify, Message is a valid model used all over the application

Comment: Try to `Yii::import('application.models.Message')` in your command `run` method, just to be sure there is no config conflicts going on

Comment: I did, no joy. I've solved it just minutes ago. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ther problem appers on Windows 7. Solution:

```
class SendMessageCommand extends CConsoleCommand {
    public function run($args) {
        Yii::$enableIncludePath = false;
        $messages = Message::model()->findAll(array('type' => 'S', 'sent' => null, 'scheduled_for' => array('$ne' => null)));
        [....]
```